# Dataflow Distinct transform example

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow, distinct-values

In my Dataflow pipeline am trying to use a [Distinct transform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Distinct.html) to reduce duplicates. I would like to try applying this to fixed 1min windows initially and use another method to deal with duplicates across the windows. This latter point will likely work best if the 1min windows are real/processing time.

I expect a few 1000 elements, text strings of a few KiB each.

I set up the Window and Distinct transform like this:

```
PCollection<String>.apply("Deduplication global window", Window
    .<String>into(new GlobalWindows())
    .triggering(Repeatedly
        .forever(AfterProcessingTime
            .pastFirstElementInPane()
            .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
        )
    )
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes()
)  
.apply("Deduplicate URLs in window", Distinct.<String>create());
```

But when I run this on GCP, I see the Distinct transform appears to emit more elements than it receives:

[image]

(So by definition they cannot be distinct unless it makes something up!)

More likely I guess I am not setting it up properly. Does anybody have an example of how to do it (I didn't really find much apart from the javadoc)? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to find distinct elements across the entire lifetime of your pipeline? Or you want each key to have a distinct element within a specific time bound?

Comment: I would like distinct elements within each processing time window (1min) - I don't want to accumulate a state larger than that.

Comment: We abandoned Dataflow for this purpose, but I have since then learnt that the extra output elements would normally be due to an error in a batch of elements, causing the whole batch to be reprocessed and recounted, so actually the Output collection size doesn't mean anything in terms of uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to remove duplicates within 1 min window;

You can make use of Fixed Windows with the default trigger rather than using a Global window with a Processing time trigger.

```
Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(60))));
```

This followed by the distinct transform will remove any repeated keys within the 1 min window based on event time.

Comment: Thank you. Silly question: Is the default trigger event time driven? The [guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers) seems to indicate so. I require a predictable time to "deal with duplicates across the windows" unless I introduce something else, like a database allowing unique column values. Therefore, can I do this on a processing time basis?

Comment: The Fixed window will be predictable : 

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#provided-windowing-functions

For each fixed window of 1 Min the elements will be deduplicated.